# MobilePush Opens Not Recorded in ET

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I have been testing MobilePush. I have created the app and can successfully push the messages on Android and IOS devices.

However when I open the message, its not recorded in ET.

I did the following send via API:
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/push/v1/messageBatch/***********/send
[
{
"SubscriberKeys": [
"***********"
],

"Message": {
"Alert": "This is test"
}
}
]

Once I hit run got the following
[{
"tokenId": "*********",
"subscriberKeys": ["********"]
}]

The message was successfully received and opened on the device.

How can I record an open in ET?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is resolved. I need to enable the send analytics in SDK which can be found at the following link:
http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/features/analytics.html